# Ruby code auto-reloaded without Rails

Tags: ruby, pry

Working with Rails, Sinatra, Padrino... I got used to my code being auto-reloaded when I made modifications.

How can I get the same behavior while working on plain Ruby gem projects which are not a Rack based web framework.

I would like to just launch a `pry` console and inmediatly being able to test the latest modifications of my source code.

Comment: I think this magic is made possible by ActiveSupport, so it may be portable to other environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define a method somewhere that clears the old stuff from memory, and re-load all of the files that comprise your gem:

```
def reload!
  Object.send(:remove_const, :ProjectNamespace)
  path = File.expand_path("../", __FILE__)
  Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*.rb") { |f| load f }
end
```

Since you're using Pry, you can define this in your project's [`.pryrc`](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Pry-rc) if you'd like to keep it out of your the code base.

You can even define the reload logic within your inside your module, and for as long as its included among the files you're reloading, all will be well:

```
module ProjectNamespace
  module_function
  def reload!
    # Reload code
  end
end

ProjectNamespace.reload!
```

If you're in need of a more managed solution (e.g. timed reloads) you should look into a library like [Rubyworks' autoreload](http://rubyworks.github.io/autoreload/).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a run.rb script that forks a process and runs your code in that separate process. Using https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent in the parent process to watch your file system for changes, kill the child process whenever a FS change is detected and fork a new child with your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration and trying the given answers, I realized that I was thinking about my problem the wrong way.

Although it is nice having a project reload, this requires certain preparation.

For Ruby I find far more convenient having a custom shortcut on my editor to:

1. save file
2. send a `load file/path.rb` command to my Pry session

That does not require any type of extra code or configuration for each project. However the other answers can be combined with `Guard` to have auto-reloads. That was actually the title of my question, but now I realized that one keystroke solution is more practical.

Comment: ***This will not always behave as you expect***. `load` only overwrites (i.e. does not clear) previous definitions. Say you remove a method from a class: it'll still be accessible from the console after you re-`load` the file.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep it out of your codebase, you can define the method in your project's [`.pryrc` file](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Pry-rc).